# Why is my json data empty when using stringify to convert data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, stringify

When I use JSON.stringify, the data that is in it can't be send for some reason. But when I remove JSON.stringify, it does send and I would like to know why? Is there a way to controll the json data in PHP file without using stringify? Any help is much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "***/server/jsonp/data",
        callback:"test",
        success: jsonSuccess
    });


    function jsonSuccess( data ){


        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){

            if ( i == 0 ) {

                var formData = {name:"tolga",age:"25"}; // test object 

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "wp-content/themes/flex/saveJsonInfo.php",
                    data: { info: JSON.stringify(data[i]) }
                }).done(function(data2) {

                    console.log(data2);

                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The json data that I receive is something like this:

```
test([{"EniNumber":"22325326","Name":"Test Fi","StartDate":"\/Date(1381788000000)\/","Rows":[{"T":42878,"Y":51.880965,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42879,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42880,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.59}]}, {"EniNumber":"12312312","Name":"Test Fi 2","StartDate":"\/Date(13817880021300)\/","Rows":[{"T":42878,"Y":51.880965,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42879,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42880,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.59}]}])
```

This is how my PHP example file looks:

```
$json_data = $_POST['info'];

if( isset($json_data) ){
    echo json_encode( $json_data );
} else {
    echo json_encode( "What happened?" );
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating `formData` (which is an object, btw, **not** an array) and then not using it?

Comment: I used formData to test if it worked!

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `saveJsonInfo.php`, which you haven't shown. Specifically, are you looking for the data (as a string) in `$_POST['info']`? Because if not, that's your problem.

Comment: *"I used formData to test if it worked!"* Not in the code in your question, you haven't.

Comment: Yes I did use $_POST['info'] and I can see the data when not using JSON.stringify.

Comment: Then the *next* bit of missing information in the question is the content of `data`.

Comment: It was meant to test it out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39401/discussion-between-xarialon-and-t-j-crowder)